# jQuery - How to call a function after stored input values are reloaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Got this field:

```
<input id="foo" />
```

And I'm calling this function right after page load:

```
function alert_value() {
    input_value = $("#foo").val();
    alert (input_value);
}
```

In some cases the values entered by the user are stored and displayed on page refresh by the browser, which is, in my case, a valueable feature.

**Problem is,** there's a gap between page load and the moment the stored input values are loaded. Since I'm calling the function during this gap, it misses the input field value.

I get the right result when doing

```
setTimeout(alert_value, 1000);
```

But I'd rather call the function immediately after the values are reloaded.

**How to catch the moment of stored input fields values load?**

Comment: are you looking for that : https://api.jquery.com/change/ ?

Comment: @MisterJ I would think change  will help here but it doesn't fire on page load, even though the input values are being changed from "" to whatever is stored as last typed values.

Comment: In firefox my change event does fire when the browser auto-populates a form from saved form info on page load - might this be inconsistent between browsers?  Not sure.  Simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yxjssr16/1/)

Comment: Where are the values loaded from? Ajax call? You have set their value to something with the name attribute? We need more details to help.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery needs to know what object you want the data from. The object has an ID, which is "foo". In your jQuery you need to address that ID.
So basically change #id for #foo:

```
$(function(){
    /* Load this content after the page is loaded */
    function alert_value() {
        input_value = $( '#foo' ).val();
        alert (input_value);
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the correction, editted the question. But this still doens't solve the described problem.

Comment: answer corrected. Use the `$(function(){ ...code here...})` to load that code AFTER the page is loaded. Also you might want to give the `input` a value like: <input id="foo" value="bar" />

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood from your question, you want to call the function as soon as the page has reloaded completely. I think this should work correctly.

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
    input_value = $("#foo").val();
    alert (input_value);
});
```

I hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: The function is already binded to page load. There's a gap between page load and stored input values load.